# Curl magento 2 store on docker

Tags: magento2, docker, curl

I'm trying to curl a docker dev install from itself

using Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl

I get a failure and the result `SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate`

Got the options set

```
$this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Because it's local/docker I can't resolve the host

Therefore using CURLOPT_PROXY. Syntax looks like this: `https://web.magento2.docker:443`

Also tried this option: CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL

If I tail nginx logs they look like this

```
2020/06/21 23:41:48 [info] 16#16: *75 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:SSL alert number 48) while SSL handshaking, client: 172.27.0.3, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Has anyone experienced similar issue and got workaround?

On command line I can use this `curl https://web.magento2.docker --insecure`

Comment: In summary I can't see to recreate the `curl https://web.magento2.docker --insecure` behaviour using the magento `Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl` logic

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a valid SSL certificate installed for your site? If you're using a self-signed one, try using Chrome instead of Firefox and accept and proceed when it warns about the security issue.

Another option if you do not need / have an SSL certificate is to set Magento to not use SSL in the admin section:

System -> Configuration -> Web -> "Secure" (Use Secure URLs in Admin -> No)

Comment: Yep local docker install - so self signed certificate. Using curl in command line - no browser. I was hoping to work through the issue rather than configure around it. Plus good practice for when working through an actual proxy